# Finding elements in html pages with dynamic frames

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am working with a vendor developed web page (SAP BusinessObjects InfoView login page) and am trying to identify and then select a drop-down element on a page. No matter what I try, I get an exception:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
ie = Watir::Browser.new
ie.goto "http://svr-boj-bop-01.mgc.mentorg.com:8080/InfoViewApp"
ie.select_list(:id, "authenticationSelectBox").select("secLDAP")
#=> 'error: "unable to locate element, using :id=>"authenticationSelectBox", :tag_name=>"select"....'
```

I have FireFox and Firebug installed, I can use Firebug to select the element which gives me info about the element. I've tried to specify :id, :name, .div, .browser, .frame, ... nothing changes the error. My suspicion is that the inner frame(s) is creating the page dynamically, based on the select of the "Authentication", but I don't know how to check / validate that is the case.

I've searched and tried most of the suggestions on the site, nothing is helping.

The page has lots of Java code, forms, etc. Here is a snip from the page I'm trying to search for elements:

```
<body onload="logonPageLoad()">
    <div class="logonContainer">
        <div class="logonIFrame">
            <iframe id="infoView_home" width="80%" frameborder="0" align="center" title="Log On to InfoView" name="infoView_home" onload="resizeFrameToContent("infoView_home")" src="jsp/listing/blank.jsp" style="height: 287px;">
                <html class="logon_body">
                    <body class="logon_body" onload="loadInit();">
                        <div class="logon_body">
                            <div id="logonCredentials">
                                <form action="../../../PartnerPlatformService/service/app/logon.object" method="POST" name="logonForm">
                                    <div class="logon_table">
                                        <div id="authentication" class="logon_input">
                                            <label class="logon_input_label" onclick="businessobjects.webutil.accessibility.setFocusOnElement('authenticationSelectBox'); return false;" tabindex="-1" for="authenticationSelectBox"> Authentication: < /label>
                                            <select id="authenticationSelectBox" class="logonSelectBox" onchange="SetAuthType(false);resizeFrameToContent('infoView_home')" name="authType">
                                                <option value="secEnterprise" selected=""> Enterprise `</option>
                                                <option value="secLDAP"> LDAP </option>
                                                <option value="secWinAD"> Windows AD </option>
                                                <option value="secSAPR3"> SAP</option>
                                            </select>
```

Comment: sorry for all the edits/reposts. thanks much Justin Ko for pointers. I've added the full html from the page, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For elements in frames, you have to explicitly call out the frame:

```
my_frame = ie.frame(:id, "infoView_home")
my_frame.select_list(:id, "authenticationSelectBox").select("secLDAP")
```

Though it sounds like you might have already tried that. It is possible, that the element is not being loaded before Watir thinks the page is loaded. If that's the case, you can add a wait using something like the `when_present` method.

```
my_frame = ie.frame(:id, "infoView_home")
my_frame.select_list(:id, "authenticationSelectBox").when_present.select("secLDAP")
```

Note that you can do it in one line (ie you do not need the `my_frame`). It is just added to make it easier to read (ie minimize horizontal scrolling).

Comment: also, I'm getting an additional error further down in my script, this one related to the login field. I'm now getting the error below from this script snip:   my_frame.text_field(:name, "password").set "dsopen"    .error = 
[remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:5671:in `unknown': Element belongs to a different frame than the cu
rrent one - switch to its containing frame to use it (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)
          I don't see another Frame reference... should I be trying to find another type of tag?

Comment: Based on the HTML of your page, there is no text field with name "password". Does the field only appear after you change the select list? Is the select list updating the frame it is in?

Comment: yes, I think so... that's what I gather from the javascript.  When I've selected the authentication then this code is available:  <div id="password" class="logon_input">   
   <label class="logon_input_label" for="passwordTextEdit" tabindex="-1">
    Password:
   </label>   
   <input name="password" value="" class="inputTextBox logonTextBox" id="passwordTextEdit" type="password">
  </div>

Comment: interestingly the code to recognize and set the username field works as expected.    my_frame.text_field(:name, "username").set "DSOpen"

Comment: The reference for the frame might be getting messed up due to it being refreshed. Try starting from the browser as a reference: `ie.frame(:id, "infoView_home").text_field(:name, "password").set "dsopen"`

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Ok... I'm going to have to go back to class to learn watir again.  I've been trying all sorts of fancy stuff, but the basic, pedantic specification is what is working. Cheers Justin Ko!